# MySQL, multiple JOINS, one count. Can't solve on my own

Tags: mysql, join, count

There's all the documentation I should need, but I just can't figure out how to solve this one. Hope I can get help.

**contacts**

```
contactId    artistname
1            Joe
2            Diplo
3            Skrillex
4            Deadmau5
```

**groups**

```
groupId   groupname
1         House
2         Hiphop
3         Jazz
```

**contact_group**

```
id   contactId   groupId
1    1           1
2    1           2
3    2           1
4    3           3
5    4           1
6    4           2
7    4           3
```

**contact_promo**

```
id   promoId   contactId   click_date
1    1         1           2015-03-25 21:00:00
2    1         2           2015-03-25 21:00:00
3    1         3           NULL
4    1         4           2015-03-25 21:00:00
5    2         1           NULL
6    2         2           NULL
7    2         3           2015-03-25 21:00:00
8    2         4           NULL
9    3         1           2015-03-25 21:00:00
10   3         2           2015-03-25 21:00:00
11   3         3           NULL
12   3         4           2015-03-25 21:00:00
```

Part of the query I want to end up with:

```
SELECT c.contactId, c.artistname g.groupId
FROM contacts c
LEFT JOIN contact_group cg ON cg.contactId = c.contactId
LEFT JOIN groups g ON cg.groupId = g.groupId
```

This query gives me a nice overview of the thing I want to end up with except for the **rating** part.

What I want the rating to be:
The rating is a COUNT on the click_date from the table contact_promo. So for example, if contactId has 3 click_dates set, it has to show 3 next to the query above (shown in the latest grey 'code' section)

What's failing now:
When I JOIN the contact_promo table and add the COUNT(click_date), with a GROUP + ORDER by. It shows all the artists ONE time and ONE group that they're in. I want to see all the groups that one artist is in, because artists can be in more than one group at the same time. What I see now:

```
contactId   artistname   groupId   rating
1           Joe          1         3
2           Diplo        1         2
3           Skrillex     1         3
4           Deadmau5     2         5
```

As you see, comparing my currents results and my goal, is that some data is missing. I can't see all the groups the artists are in. Only one group.

The overview I want to see:

```
contactId   artistname   groupId   rating
1           Joe          1         3
2           Diplo        1         2
3           Skrillex     1         3
4           Deadmau5     2         5
1           Joe          4         3
2           Skrillex     3         3
etc.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT c.contactId, c.artistname, g.groupId, q.rating
FROM contacts c
LEFT JOIN contact_group cg ON cg.contactId = c.contactId
LEFT JOIN groups g ON cg.groupId = g.groupId
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT cp.contactId, count(click_date) rating FROM contact_promo cp 
    GROUP BY cp.contactId
) q ON q.contactId = c.contactId
```

Or here it is in a fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/212c6/1

Did you want the count of click_dates to also include the ones that are NULL?

Is there any possibility that a contact wont be in a group? if not, they can be inner joins, not left joins.

Comment: No, I don't want the NULL dates. This is exactly what I needed :) Thanks